Ugly workaround for session expiration in a Next.js app using Cognito. Is there a better solution?
I am writing a Next.js app for a client. The app is using NextAuth to authenticate users via AWS Cognito (OAuth, OIDC, JWT, etc.). Currently, I am using the Cognito hosted UI for authentication. All is working well. However, the client would like sessions to expire if the users close the browser without explicitly logging out. I modified my NextAuth config to use a JWT cookie that expires after only 3 minutes and a keep-alive that keeps the session open as long as the user remains on the site. So far, so good... except not really.
The Problem: When the user is logged in, closes the browser, and reopens the app 5 minutes later, my local app session is correctly expired. This triggers a redirect to Cognito. However, Cognito still has a valid session/cookie for the user that is hard-coded to expire after 1 hour. This causes Cognito to immediately redirect the user back to my app with a new, valid token. I was hoping they would have to re-authenticate. Since this cookie is not configurable. The only way I see to remove/expire it is to redirect the browser to the Cognito logout page.
This leads to my ugly solution... It works, mind you, but I really don't like it! What I did was configure NextAuth such that when the user wants to log in, it first redirects them to the Cognito Logout URL with a callback URL to my app's login URL which sends then sends them back to Cognito (dizzy yet?). Consider this example:

First, assume user is already authenticated and is on my site.
User closes the browser
Five minutes later, the user reopens their browser
NextAuth detects that the user is not authenticated (JWT has expired) and redirects the user to the Cognito Logout URL
Cognito logs the user out and redirects them back to my site. Note that the user does not actually see Cognito here because all of the HTTP responses are redirects.
My app then redirects the user back to Cognito's normal login URL.
The user sees the Cognito login page prompting them for their credentials.
Upon successful authentication, the user lands back on my site with a new JWT.

Wow, yuck! ...but it works and isn't a bad UX. Please tell me there is a better way! My own thoughts are:

Accept the 1-hour expiration time on Cognito (not great security wise)
Don't use Cognito (too late for me)


There are standard patterns for this when using OpenID Connect:

You send the prompt=login request parameter to force a new login
You can apply your own logic to decide when to set it
You can also specify a max_age parameter, after which the authorization server should require a new login
When using max_age you also get an auth_time claim issued to the ID token

Unfortunately though, at the time of this answer, I believe Cognito doesn't support the prompt parameter. Until it does, your current type of workaround (and extra logout redirect) is required.

Thanks, that is at least a helpful confirmation. Yes, I did try prompt=login and it has no effect with Cognito. I think I'm going to settle with the 1-hour session expiration at least for now.

I knew going into this that Cognito was pretty bare-bones and accepted that but I at least expected that it would fully implement the OpenID Connect specification. It does not. For the prompt=login option, the spec states:
"The Authorization Server SHOULD prompt the End-User for reauthentication. If it cannot reauthenticate the End-User, it MUST return an error, typically login_required."
